# Problem with git: remote origin already exists

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add my code to github and I am very confused by git.

Here is my code,

```
$ git init 
$ git add . 
$ git commit -m "First commit" 
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/anhbui2904/xxx.git 
$ git push origin master
```

My problem is, when I tried to entered the code

```
$ git commit -m "First commit"
On branch master Your branch is up to date with origin/master
```

then, with this code
`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/anhbui2904/xxx.git` there was this error `fatal: remote origin already exists`

I tried `git fetch --all` and `git reset --hard origin/master` but still can not solve this problem.

I am a newbie and very confused with this problem, could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: That message that is shown after you tried to commit is not something that happens when you commit. Are you sure that is accurate?

Comment: And, unless you are running other things that you are not specifying, the original sequence of commands (assuming you already had things set up on that directory where you are working) is correct and should not give you any problem.... except for having the repo on github already set up with some content on a revision and in that case git will tell you about having to merge stuff before pushing.

Answer (score 1):

You should try another name for the remote.

i.e.

```
git remote add othername https://github.com/anhbui2904/xxx.git
```

And then, when pushing, call this name.

```
git push othername master
```

Another approach, would be removing the current origin.

```
git remote rm origin
```

And then adding it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try another URL for your default remote (`origin`), use `git remote set-url ...`:

```sh
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/anhbui2904/xxx.git
```

You can also add another URL as a new remote, and then push your commits to it:

```sh
git remote add <a-meaningful-remote-name> https://github.com/anhbui2904/xxx.git
git push -u <a-meaningful-remote-name> master
```

`git push` is a shortcut of `git push origin`, it pushes your commits to the default remote, namely the `origin`. If you want to push commits to other remote, use `git push <your-remote-name>` instead.

Some other useful commands for `git remote`:

```sh
# rename a remote
git remote rename <old-name> <new-name>

# remove a remote
git remote remove <remote-name>

# manual for `git remote`
git remote --help
```